# Trying to turn inner and out tuples into inner and outer lists

Tags: python, arrays, list, tuples

Ok, so I've got information in the form of

```
(('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('H', 'I', 'J'))
```

and I would like to convert this to

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

What is the best/easiest way to do this?

Comment: Nice catch. Great programmer's eye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> data = (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('H', 'I', 'J'))
>>> [list(tup) for tup in data]
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Answer (score 5):

List comprehension:

```
tpl = (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('H', 'I', 'J'))

lst = [list(x) for x in tpl]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('H', 'I', 'J'))
print map(list, a)
```

prints

```
[['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 'F'], ['H', 'I', 'J']]
```

Comment: This won't work in python3, because `map()` returns a generator.

Comment: In Python 3, simply use `print(list(map(list, a)))`.

Comment: IMO, it makes it harder for beginners to get advice on Py2.x if people are always chiming in with, "that doesn't work in 3.x".  Even when it is true, the differences are usually shallow.  It is best to give advice of "what does work" than to unnecessarily convey a message of brokenness.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the structure is only two levels, try:

```
x = (('A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'E', 'F'), ('H', 'I', 'J'))
y = [ list(t) for t in x ]
```

If there might be deeper nesting, you'll want recursion -- see F.J's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple recursive solution for any number of nested tuples:

```
>>> tup = (('A', ('B', 'C')), ('D', 'E', 'F', ('H', 'I', 'J')))
>>> listify = lambda x: map(listify, x) if isinstance(x, tuple) else x
>>> listify(tup)
[['A', ['B', 'C']], ['D', 'E', 'F', ['H', 'I', 'J']]]
```

For Python 3 replace `map(listify, x)` with `list(map(listify, x))`.